# Select first result from one collection using group by and adding into another collection

Tags: linq, collections

I have 2 collection and I getting problem to add the data from one collection to another by querying it using LINQ.

The first collection class MyTestCase object has list of test case results for each machine with timestamp. One machine one or more test case from another collection TestResultsInfo .Also test cases results are multiple instance with results as pass or fail.

I created below LINQ query to achieve this but that look more hardcoded and it throw exception if there is no test case result for any of the test.

Can you please suggest me pointer.

```
public class MyTestCase
{
     public string MachineName { get; set; }

    public string TestName { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}


public class TestResultsInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    public string Test1 { get; set; }

    public string Test2 { get; set; }

    public string Test3 { get; set; }

    public string Test4 { get; set; }

}

        List<MyTestCase> TestResultList = GetTestResults();

        List<TestResultsInfo> testResultInfo = new List<TestResultsInfo>();

        var results = from p in TestResultList
                      group p by p.MachineName into grps
                      select new
                      {
                          MachineName = grps.Key,
                          Test1 = grps.FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.TestName == "Test1").Result,
                          Test2 = grps.FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.TestName == "Test2").Result,
                          Test3 = grps.FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.TestName == "Test3").Result,
                          Test4 = grps.FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.TestName == "Test4").Result
                      };

        int testResultId = 1;

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            TestResultsInfo machineTestInfo = new TestResultsInfo();
            machineTestInfo.ID = testResultId++;
            machineTestInfo.MachineName = result.MachineName;
            machineTestInfo.Test1 = result.Test1;
            testResultInfo.Add(machineTestInfo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# 6, you use null operand to avoid NullReferenceException

```
var testResultInfo = TestResultList.GroupBy(x => x.MachineName)
                                   .Select((x, i) => new TestResultsInfo
                                   {
                                       ID = i + 1,
                                       MachineName = x.Key,
                                       Test1 = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TestName == "Test1")?.Result,
                                       Test2 = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TestName == "Test2")?.Result,
                                       Test3 = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TestName == "Test3")?.Result,
                                       Test4 = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TestName == "Test4")?.Result
                                   })
                                   .ToList();
```

But if you aren't using C# 6, you use the DefaultIfEmpty method from LINQ.

```
var @default = new MyTestCase();
var testResultInfo = TestResultList.GroupBy(x => x.MachineName)
                                   .Select((x, i) => new TestResultsInfo
                                   {
                                       ID = i + 1,
                                       MachineName = x.Key,
                                       Test1 = x.Where(y => y.TestName == "Test1").DefaultIfEmpty(@default).First().Result,
                                       Test2 = x.Where(y => y.TestName == "Test2").DefaultIfEmpty(@default).First().Result,
                                       Test3 = x.Where(y => y.TestName == "Test3").DefaultIfEmpty(@default).First().Result,
                                       Test4 = x.Where(y => y.TestName == "Test4").DefaultIfEmpty(@default).First().Result
                                   })
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto !!  using c#5.0 solution getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception . I just changed (x => x.TestName == "Test1" to (x1 => x1.TestName == "Test1") as it was giving error as x is already used . Do i need to change anything else ?

Comment: has one more query , to avoid duplicate the question content asking here   If i need to add more Test in TestResultsInfo class, is that possible dynamically ??  Like now i have Test1 ,2,3,4 so in future i might i have Test 1,2,5,6.  Thanks for the help !!!